# What is the canonical way to type empty __slots__ (or empty tuple)?

Tags: python, tuples, mypy, python-typing, slots

If I type slots:

```py
class Foo:
    __slots__: Tuple[()] = tuple()
```

Then, in strict mode, mypy (0.812) tells me:

```
Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[<nothing>, ...]", variable has type "Tuple[]")
```

I can write:

```py
__slots__: Tuple[()] = cast(Tuple[()], tuple())
```

But this is ugly. What is the canonical way to do this? What does mypy mean by `Tuple[<nothing>, ...]`? Tuples are immutable so surely an empty tuple shouldn't be... a variable amount of nothing..?

Comment: More importantly: *Why* do you want to do this? ``__slots__ = ()`` will be correctly inferred.

Comment: Ah -- right ... I thought `()` and `tuple()` were the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not the annotation but the value. Use a *literal* tuple to unambiguously represent tuples of fixed size, including the empty tuple:

```py
class Foo:
    __slots__: Tuple[()] = ()
```

Note that MyPy will correctly infer the type of this `__slots__` even without an annotation.

---

The *callable* `tuple` has a return type of `Tuple[T, ...]`, since for most inputs the output length is not known. [The call `tuple()` is not special cased.](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6283) As with `tuple()` there is no value to infer `T` from, [there is no type inhabiting `T` – its type is `<nothing>`](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3030).